# PHP Form not POSTing the files

Tags: php, file, post

Ok so I know there a bunch of questions already out there on this topic but none of their solutions are working for me. I have verified that file_uploads is turned on and that my file does not exceed the file max. When I submit my form, the POST data contains everything but the file field and I can't figure out why. The response I get from my PHP script also does not include the values of 1 for the length of the files array and does not include the 1 for moving the file successfully. It seems as though the files were never posted. I'm running out of ideas though, any help is much appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/RK/submitQuestion.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>Personal Info</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>

        <td><input type="text" id="submitFirstName" name="submitFirstName" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>

        <td><input type="text" id="submitLastName" name="submitLastName" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>

        <td><input type="text" id="submitEmail" name="submitEmail" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>Question</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Please enter your question here:</td>

        <td>
        <textarea name="submitComments" style="resize: none;" rows="5">
</textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Attachment:</td>

        <td><input type="file" id="submitUserFiles" name="submitUserFiles" multiple=
        "multiple" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('submitUserFiles', $_FILES)) {
    //Loop through each file adding its location to an array
    $len = count($_FILES['submitUserFiles']['name']);
    echo $len;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['submitUserFiles']['tmp_name'];
        $name     = $_FILES['submitUserFiles']['name'];
        echo move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\uploads\\' . $name);
        $mail->addAttachment('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\uploads\\' . $name);
    }
}
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'Thank you for your question. Your message has been sent. Redirecting you back to where you were.';
}
?>
```

POST Data:

[image: POST Data Screen]

PHP Response:

```
Thank you for your question. Your message has been sent. Redirecting you back to where you were.
```

What I'm expecting to see is:

```
11Thank you for your question. Your message has been sent. Redirecting you back to where you were.
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `var_dump()` unstead of `echo` for debugging. `echo` does not output false boolean values. Does `move_uploaded_file()` return false? If so, turn error logging on and see what that yields.

Comment: Ok yes I tried that as well and it isn't outputting anything. My guess is there is no array key under $FILES with that name since it doesn't appear to be entering the IF Statement at all.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES);` before your if statement. What does that give you?

Comment: array(o) { } Thank you for your question. Your message has been sent. Redirecting you back to where you were.

Comment: What are your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_file_size` values in your php.ini file? Check the file you're uploading is not larger than these values.

Comment: upload_max_filesize=200M, post_max_size=200M. test.txt=3.12KB

Comment: Perhaps, check the permissions on the temp directory? If the server has nowhere to put the file, it may not show in the array. You can find the value for this in your php.ini file under `upload-tmp-dir`. If it is not there, I see you are running IIS, so by default it will be `c:\windows\temp`.

Comment: Yes I have already changed that to a set location C:\inetpub\wwwroot\temp which has full read/write perms. Its also interesting to note I have another form & script that work completely fine, the only difference is variable names and that the other form that works is submitted using ajax.